# about data transactions

Tags: transaction

A question , Friends.

Do data transactions need the milestones of the coordinator for the nodes to validate them, just like value transactions?

If the coordinator stopped , could data transactions be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Data transactions do not need that kind of validation and can still be used when the coordinator is down.

Very briefly, what the coordinator does is confirm a certain valid history of value transactions, which is needed for new value transactions to get validated and confirmed and to prevent all kinds of attacks, like parasite chains and double spends.

Strictly speaking you could thus also keep sending value transactions when the coordinator is down, but those transactions just won't get confirmed as their history is not confirmed by the coordinator.

NOTE: This will all be obsolete after Coordicide, when the coordinator is removed from the network and other means are implemented to reach consensus between nodes about the valid history of transactions.